# multiple column table in a 2 column article

Tags: tables, two-column, article

I can't seem to grasp an understanding of tables in LaTeX.
I'm trying to set up several tables in a document with 2 columns. I'm trying to maintain the tables within a single column of the article but there seems to be overlap, as well as the tables start at the beginning of each page, rather than staying in the sections I'm intending them to be in. Should I be making these tables span over both columns?

[image: Overlap of table onto second column]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,lipsum,cuted,capt-of}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\section*{Results}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\dimexpr.4\linewidth-
\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.6\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr.4\linewidth-\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.6\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr.4\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
\toprule 
Compound & Theoretical Yield (g) & Experimental Yield (g) & Percent Yield & Percent Composition of Total Product \\
\midrule
Total Final Product & 2.90 & 1.6853 & 58.1 & \\
2-methyl-2-butene & 2.60 & 1.56 & & 92.60756 \\
2-methyl-1-butene & 0.30 & 0.12 & &7.39244 \\
\bottomrule %inserts single line
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:2} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide the currently-missing `\end{tabular*}` directive and change `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` to `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}`, respectively. Unfortunately, your table still won't have a chance of being typeset correctly, as the widths of the five columns sum to about `2.4\linewidth`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: not sure how it happened but my LaTeX file has the \end{tabular*}
I'm trying to place the 5 column table within the 1 column of the article. as well as keep it within the selected section. as it sits the tables keep moving to a new page.

Comment: Off-topic: the options for `textfont` -- `up` (upright shape) and `it` (italic shape) -- are mutually exclusive. Use one or the other option, *but not both*.

Answer (score 8):

To typeset a full-width table in a two-column document, you must use a `table*` environment. Note that LaTeX always places `table*` environments (and `figure*` environments too) at the top of a page.

Your table has five columns. Three of the five cell headers are quite long and have to be line-broken. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment and a centered version of the `X` column type for columns 2 thru 5. For column 1, use the basic `l` column type.

[image]

An additional comment: Given that the experimental yields (in grams) appear to be measured with no more than 3 digits of precision, reporting the percentage yields with 7 digits of precision borders on the preposterous. Reporting "92.6%" and "7.4%" (or, if you insist, "92.61%" and "7.39%") would be more in the spirit of things, I believe.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,cuted,capt-of}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,
            columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small, labelfont={bf,up},
                         textfont ={it,up}]{caption} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\section*{Results}

\begin{table*}  % will be placed at top of a page
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l CCCC @{}}
\toprule 
Compound & Theoretical Yield (g) & Experimental Yield (g) & Percent Yield & Percent Composition of Total Product \\
\midrule
Total Final Product & 2.90 & 1.6853 & 58.1 \\[1ex]
2-methyl-2-butene   & 2.60 & 1.56   & &   92.60756 \\
2-methyl-1-butene   & 0.30 & 0.12   & &    7.39244 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:2}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up query posted by the OP: If this were my document, I'd focus my editing efforts on simplifying and streamlining the tabular material so that it can fit in a single column. Something along the following lines, say.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang, small, labelfont={bf,up},
                         textfont ={it,up}]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\section*{Results}

\begin{table} [h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} l CCC @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yield} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
Compound & Theoretical & Experimental & Percent of total\\
& (g) & (g) \\
\midrule
Total Final Product & 2.90 & 1.68 &  \\[0.5ex]
2-methyl-2-butene   & 2.60 & 1.56 & 92.6 \\
2-methyl-1-butene   & 0.30 & 0.12 & \phantom{0}7.4 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
Yield ratio, experimental to theoretical: 58.1\%.
\caption{GC parameters on \dots}
\label{table:2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to maintain the table within the same section?

Comment: @ChristopherG - That depends on how long the section is. How long is it?

Comment: @ChristopherG - With a bit of planning, it should be feasible to place the table in a single column. That’s probably what I would do if this were my paper.

Comment: Beatifully done, like always. But `Total Final Product & 2.90 & 1.69` would be better rounding ;)

Comment: @thymaro - Thanks! The OP's original table features a slight discrepancy: The sum of the individual experimenal yields is 1.68, yet the overall yield is listed as 1.6853, which should get rounded to 1.69, the number you propose. I trust the OP will see fit to work out what's correct and/or appropriate... :-)

Comment: apologies for the misunderstanding. I had used a top loading balance to weigh the masses of the products out. when I had formulated the table I did not place all the decimal places for the first 3 columns. also, the percent composition was recorded for a gas chromatograph mass spectrometer. So all the decimal places were to be reported.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to swap row and columns, use `tabularx` and play with some parameters:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1, top=32mm, columnsep=20pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, cuted,capt-of, tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\section*{Results}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{3}{c}@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Compound} \\
 \cmidrule{2-4}
 & \makecell{Total Final\\ Product} & \makecell[r]{2-methyl\\-2-butene} & \makecell[r]{2-methyl\\-1-butene} \\
\midrule
Theoretical Yield (g) & 2.90 & 2.60 & 0.30 \\
 Experimental Yield (g) &1.6853 & 1.56 & 0.12 \\
 Percent Yield &58.1 & &\\
 \makebox[\hsize][l]{Percent Composition} \makebox[\hsize][l]{of Total Product} & & 92.60756 & 7.39244 \\
\bottomrule %inserts single line
\end{tabularx}
\caption{GC parameters on}
\label{table:2} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}

\end{document}&
```

[image]